# Parse a Namespace in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, rest, web-services, namespaces

I have a fairly simple web service response. How I can parse the response in a way that I could get the value of namespace ns2:count.

Web Service Response

```
    <availableSlots xmlns:ns5="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" xmlns:ns2="http://bindings.egain.com/chat" xmlns:ns4="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" xmlns:ns3="jabber:client">
<ns2:count>1</ns2:count>
</availableSlots>
```

My JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: "https://myserver/system/company/chat/fake/capacity/1007",
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (data) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data),
            $xml = $(xmlDoc),
            $name = $xml.find("ns2\\:count");
        $("#AvailableAgents").html($name);
        alert($name);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.responseText + "\n" + xhr.status + "\n" + thrownError);
    }
});
```

});

this way my alert shows object [Object]. How I can get the value 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, parseXML dose not work for me but I was able to get the values as;

1. I get the xml attribute which is availableSlots
2. Then I get the valueof ns2 namespace

   var slots =  $(data).find('availableSlots');

   var numberOfAgents = $(slots).find("ns2\:count").text();